# Redefine paragraph-start and paragraph-separate in Emacs bibtex-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, auctex

I'm looking for an easy way to move quickly up or down by a single BibTeX entry when in `bibtex-mode`.  Of course I could write a function that searches for the relevant lines, but it seems more sensible to me to redefine how `bibtex-mode` sees paragraphs as that will allow me to use default keybindings for navigation (`M-}` and `M-{` for instance).  I tried the following, since each BibTeX entry starts with the `@` character and there's a newline between all entries:

`(setq paragraph-start "@.*"
       paragraph-separate "\n"))`

But this doesn't seem to have any effect, at least not when using `forward-paragraph` and `backward-paragraph`.  What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm aware of integration with imenu and `bibtex-search-entry`, but those serve a slightly different purpose.

Comment: In any case, `paragraph-start` needs to match whatever `paragraph-end` matches -- see the doc string.  See the doc strings of each and this comment in `paragraphs.el`: `paragraph-start requires a hard newline, but paragraph-separate does not:
It is assumed that paragraph-separate is distinctive enough to be believed
whenever it occurs, while it is reasonable to set paragraph-start to
something very minimal, even including "." (which makes every hard newline
start a new paragraph).`

Comment: See also [**this**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/3kVlF9ryTEk)

Comment: And see node `Paragraphs` in the Emacs manual and node `Standard Regexps` in the Elisp manual.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I imagine I can get `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate` working with all this, but it seems that it might not be the best approach.  Maybe I'll just write functions to search after all.

Answer (score 4):

WRT mentioned missing effect - leaving aside the regexp-question commented by Drews already:

Modes often set variables,  which might overwrite values from init-file. To set variables after a mode is loaded, use "add-hook".  Like that it should be recognised:

```
(add-hook 'bibtex-mode-hook (lambda ()(setq paragraph-start "START-VALUE" paragraph-separate "SEP-VALUE")))
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I actually have this exact line already, but just chopped most of it out for the sake of brevity.  I guess I should have been more clear in case others ever read this.